# Understanding Boole's / Bonferroni Inequality in the context of p-hacking

Tags: p-value, probability-inequalities

I'm reading an article in the most recent issue of ORMS Today that touches on p-hacking and makes the following comment:

*The null hypothesis is rejected when the p-value is sufficiently small, under the assumption that the alternative is the more likely explanation.  Of course, in any large number of experiments, a "significant" result (i.e. one with a low p-value) is increasingly likely to occur, as quantified by the Bonferroni inequality.*  From "The joys and perils of statistics" by James J. Swain, ORMS Today, February 2017.

I'm trying to understand how Bonferroni's inequality relates to p-hacking as mentioned by the author.  The inequality I presume he is talking about is

$$
p(\bigcup_i E_i ) \leq \sum_i p(E_i). 
$$

It seems that we'd like the left-hand-side to be smaller, as this would result in a "significant" p-value.  So it seems that Boole's inequality is quantifying this probability since the right-hand-side will grow (it is nondecreasing) with more observations, while the p-value on the left may not increase, therefore giving the appearance of a significant result when in fact this is merely due to chance.  Is this a correct understanding of this remark?  Am I missing anything else?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $E_i$ in this case is the event that null-hypothesis $H_{0i}$ gets falsely rejected. The probability $P(\bigcup_i E_i)$ is what's known as the family-wise error rate (FWER). It's not a p-value as such, it's the probability that *at least one null* is falsely rejected. That is to say the probability of getting at least one "falsely" small p-value.

The inequality gives you a worst-case scenario for this probability, saying that it might be as bad as $\sum_i P(E_i)$ under certain conditions. In a sense, if you want a greater chance of a false rejection, just test more hypotheses.

Hence Bonferroni's method for dealing with multiple testing: For $m$ hypotheses, reject $H_{0i}$ if the p-value $P_i < \alpha/m$. This gives
$$
P(\bigcup_{i=1}^m E_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^m P(E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha/m = \alpha,
$$
so that the upper bound on the FWER is the same as if you did one hypothesis test.